# In AnyLogic, I am wondering if there is a way to free my agents in the wait block after a specified amount of time?

Tags: wait, anylogic, production

One of the processes in my production line is a clamp station. Pieces of wood are glued together and can't be moved until after their drying time is complete. What would you suggest using to demonstrate this in AnyLogic? I was thinking a wait block, but I am not sure how to free an agent after a given amount of time.

Comment: Why not a Delay block?

Answer (score 1):

There's a timeout option in the wait block that you can use and setup a defined timeout... you can find that in the advanced section of the properties, a checkbox called "enabled exit on timeout"

Note that the exit port for the timeout is on the top right of the block.